# Search list in local JSON received with axios (Vue 3)

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I had a problem when I want to filter data with search box. I had to use code from this reference
[Vue2 Search in List received via Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758624/vue2-search-in-list-received-via-axios) and still not working.

I want to get data from my local json file (that I put in public folders). Here's my db.json file:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nama": "Skin10004",
      "deskripsi": "Madagascar Centella Toning"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nama": "Some By Mi",
      "deskripsi": "AHA-BHA-PHA 30 Days"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "nama": "Avoskin",
      "deskripsi": "Your Skin Bae Series Toner"
    }
  ]
}
```

With axios, i'm successfully get all the data. But my problem is, my search box can't filter the data when user type on it. Here's my code in Products.vue:

```
// Here's my view code
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <div class="container">

    <!-- Here's my search box but fail to filter the data-->
      <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input
              v-model="search"
              type="search"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Cari disini .."
              aria-label="Cari"
              aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
              @keyup="searchProducts"
            />

            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
                <b-icon-search></b-icon-search>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <!-- Here's where my product display and success to display all data -->
      <div class="row mb-4">
        <div
          class="col-md-4 mt-4"
          v-for="product in products"
          :key="product.id"
        >
          <CardProduct :product="product" />
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<script>
// Navbar and CardProduct is not the issue
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar.vue";
import CardProduct from "@/components/CardProduct.vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Products",
  components: {
    Navbar,
    CardProduct,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      products: [], // Where I store the data to display in view
      search: null, // initialize search null
    };
  },

  // Where I grab all the data in db.json
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("/db.json")
      .then((response) => this.setProducts(response.data.products))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  },

  // Where I store the data to display in view
  methods: {
    setProducts(data) {
      this.products = data;
    },
  },

  // Here's my problem. Search can't filter the display data
  computed: {
    searchProducts: function () {
      let searchTerm = (this.search || "").toLowerCase();
      return this.products.filter(function (product) {
        let nama = (product.nama || "").toLowerCase();
        let deskripsi = (product.deskripsi || "").toLowerCase();
        return (
          nama.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1 || deskripsi.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1
        );
      });
    },
  },
  
  created() {
    setTimeout(() => (this.products = products), 500);
  },

};
</script>
```

In console, i've got an error like this:

1. Uncaught ReferenceError: products is not defined
2. [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: handler.apply is not a function"
3. TypeError: handler.apply is not a function

Thanks.

Comment: Part of the problem (particularly numbers 2 and 3) is that you're binding `@keyup` to a computed property. A computed is not exactly a function, thus `handler.apply is not a function`. You should probably make `searchProducts` a method rather than a computed.

Answer (score 1):

> `Uncaught ReferenceError: products is not defined`

The error is likely in `created()`, where `products` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere:

```js
export default {
  created() {                            
    setTimeout(() => (this.products = products), 500);
  },                                  ^^^^^^^^
}
```

It doesn't look like you even need it, since your `mounted()` hook populates `this.products`. Just remove the `created()` hook altogether.

> `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: handler.apply is not a function"`

This error is caused by your `keyup` binding to the computed prop `searchProducts`, which doesn't quite make sense. I suspect you actually want the displayed product list to be automatically filtered by the user's search term. The problem is the displayed product list loops through all `products`, but it should be looping through `searchProducts`:

```html
<div
  class="col-md-4 mt-4"
  v-for="product in searchProducts"
  :key="product.id"
>
  <CardProduct :product="product" />
</div>
```

Just remove the `@keyup` binding, and update the `v-for` variable as shown above.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your help. It works now